# Repeat the whole Tablix on every Page SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have Multiple Tablixes in My SSRS Report all pointing to the same dataset but have different groupings. I want My first Tablix(which has the summary data) want to be displayed on all the pages of the SSRS Report. Anyone please help me how can i achieve this one?

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS you have the ability to put a tablix, inside of a tablix. So assuming you setup your sections appropriately, you should be able to achieve this.

Put your tablix that you want to repeat inside of a single header row, then set the header row of the parent table to repeat on each page.

**EDIT:**
[image: diagram of the concept]

Comment: But i have a column group on my tablix so i cannot really merge the whole row cells to put the tablix inside it.

Comment: You don't have to merge and columns or rows in the child tablix. You can copy/paste your existing structure inside of one row in the parent tablix. See my edited post